# (How to) access a jar in /WEB-INF/{lib|classes} from a class in $CATALINA_{HOME|BASE}/lib

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, classloader

Let's say I have a class A that is part of A.jar, where A.jar is in

> $CATALINA_HOME/lib

or

> $CATALINA_BASE/lib.

I have another class B that is part of B.jar, where B.jar is in

> /WEB-INF/lib

or

> /WEB-INF/classes

A has a reference to B.

According to [how class loading works in tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) it should not be possible for A to see B, since everything in /WEB-INF/lib is only accessible by the web application deployed to WEB-INF itself. Indeed, when trying this with Tomcat 7.0.41, this does not work, i.e. A cannot find the class B.

However, let's assume I indeed **want** A to be able to reference B, (how) can I do it in Tomcat 7.x?

Answer (score -1):

According to the link you posted:

Normally, application classes should NOT be placed here. The locations searched by this class loader are defined by the common.loader property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. The default setting will search the following locations in the order they are listed:

1. unpacked classes and resources in $CATALINA_BASE/lib
2. JAR files in $CATALINA_BASE/lib
3. unpacked classes and resources in $CATALINA_HOME/lib
4. JAR files in $CATALINA_HOME/lib

So unless you made changes to the catalina.properties file, I don't see how your class in A.jar can find B.jar.